# Cannot add VM to Standard Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure-load-balancer

I have an Azure standard internal load balancer inside a VNET that contains several virtual machines.  Two of the VMs are not listed as options when I want to add them to a back end pool of the load balancer.  They are were created under ARM and not included in any other load balancer pool.  They are also in the same VNET that is associated to the backend pool.

If I create a basic load balancer, I can see them and successfully add them to the pool.  Is there documentation on the VM requirements that must be met before you can add a VM to a pool within a standard load balancer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add the backend pool, you will see **Only VMs in the same region with standard SKU public IP or no public IP can be attached to this load balancer.**

[image]

In this case, you can randomly disable the public IP address from the virtual machine---network interface---Ip configurations---ipconfig1---disabled---save. Then you can add the desired VMs to backend pool again.

Comment: I did not set-up a public ip address (for vmss) to begin with: so there is "no public ip" address. still I can't choose my vmss as backend pool. why?

Comment: The same region vm with your load balancer? or standard sku LB?

Comment: Yes, vm scale set and internal standard sku azure load balancer are in the same region. scale set doesn't show in "virtual network" search box in screenshot above. Maybe this works only via ARM?

Comment: Sure, in your case, you should use a basic sku LB. Standard SKU could find VMs in a vnet instead of scale set.

Comment: But what if I want http_s_ health probes whihc only the standard sku is capable of?

Comment: Could you post your question with more details about your purpose? it is not a good way to communicate under this reply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187097/discussion-between-baouss-and-nancy-xiong).

Comment: I mean you could post a new question.